# Wireless is connected but keeps showing "problem loading page"

Tags: 11.10, wireless, firefox, macbook

My wireless does *not* keep disconnecting to the point where I have to manually enable it. I just manually enable it as soon as I log in. Just clarifying as I read some other issues like this.

I'm using Firefox, and every other Google search I run shows me

> The connection was reset while loading the page

page

Never had this problem before, and not sure where to start.

I'm on a MacBook, running Ubuntu 11.10 and Gnome Shell

any thoughts?

Comment: Check your proxy settings...

Comment: Hm? what am I checking for? And what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Firefox:

- Go to Tools Menu > Preferences > Advanced > Network Tab.
- In that click "Settings" in Connection section and select option that says "No Proxy".
- Click "Ok" in every open dialog and close it.

Now try to access any webpage and see if it connects then.